# Extracting values from 'textarea' inside loop in an html table to update the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called 'Spatula' inside my mysql database. It has data filled in it. I'm displaying this data on the webpage through php code using 'html table'. The last column of the table is called 'Order Quantity' which is a 'textarea.' Users could put in the quantity of Spatulas they want by putting in integer values inside the textarea. The problem is that I don't know how to select all the values from the text area so that I could use that to update my database. What I want to do is to update the last row inside the mysql table according to the user input.  Say, if user orders 2 Spatulas of id 3, 2 spatulas should be deducted from the mysql table.  Could you tell me how to extract data from my code from the textarea and put and use it to update my database?

Here is my code that displays values from the database and displays it on the webpage:

```
<html>

<Title>
  WebPage1
</Title>
<head>
<p><h1> Orders </h1></p>
</head>

<body>
<p>Customer Details: </p>
  <textarea rows="6" cols="60">
  </textarea>
  <br>
Responsible Staff Member:
<textarea rows="0.5" cols="4" style="width: 188px; height: 22px;">

</textarea>

<p> </p>

<?php

//replace the following with your details. Dbname is your username by default.
$con = mysqli_connect("info20003db.eng.unimelb.edu.au","sjayswal","sjayswal_2016","sjayswal");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Could not connect to MySQL for the following reason: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


/* this lists the name and release date of Contents from Spatula */

echo "<table border='1'>";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from Spatula");

echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>idSpatula</td><td>ProductName</td><td>Type</td><td>Size</td><td>Colour</td><td>Price</td><td>Quantity currently in stock</td>
    <td>Order Quantity</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['idSpatula'] . "</td><td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td><td>".$row['Type']."</td><td>". $row['Size'].
    "</td><td>".$row['Colour']."</td><td>".$row['Price']."</td><td>"
    .$row[' QuantityInStock']."</td><td> <input type= 'textarea' name='textput' id='spatid' value='0'></textarea></td>";

    echo "</tr>";


}

echo "</table>";

echo "</br>";
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';


if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

$values=$_POST['textput'];

}






mysqli_close($con);
?>






</body>



</html>
```

[This is how the webpage looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GADQo.png)[This is how my database looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8M3u.png)

Answer (score 0):

PHP and html "run in two different threads" the server will generate your first part of your html then it will execute your php code and then generate the last part, so you can't pass the user input to that php code, you need to do something like an ajax call to your server with the data the user input and then save it in your db

Comment: I just need to extract the textarea value inside a variable. I can do that, can't I?

Comment: Kindly look at my database and webpage from the link that I've provided.

Comment: Add an id to the textarea and use javascript like document.getElementById("textareaId").value but it won't send it to you database, you need to send it to your server and save it from your server. I think you might me needing some extra reading

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<input type='hidden' name='ids[]' value='".$row['idSpatula']."'>
<textarea name='textput".$row['idSpatula']."'  value='0'></textarea>
```

inside ur while loop

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    foreach($ids as $id)
    {
        $text_box_value = $_POST['textput'.$id];
        //write code for updation
    }
}
```